# Action Creator and Reducer not console.logging, but the component is connected

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, state

I am trying to connect a React component to Action creator and dispatch action to reducers and render data. I am using Redux as a state management. 
I am not sure why it isn't console logging, because it shows I connected action creator fine.

Also I am wondering would you rather use redux promise as middleware or redux thunk?

SearchBar.js

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { connect } from 'react-redux';
        import { searchArtist } from './actions';

        class SearchBar extends Component{
            constructor(){
                super();
                this.state = {
                    query:'test'
                }
                this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                this.clearForm = this.clearForm.bind(this);
                // this.searchArtist = this.searchArtist.bind(this);
            }

            clearForm(e){
                this.setState({
                    query:''
                })
            }

            handleChange(e){
                this.setState({
                    query:e.target.value
                });
            }
            render(){
                console.log(this.props)
                return (
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={this.props.searchArtist}>
                            <label>Search For Your Favourite Song</label>
                            <input type="text" value={this.state.query} onClick={this.clearForm} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

        function mapStateToProps(state){
            return{
                search:state.search
            }
        }

        export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Action Creator

index.js

```
        import axios from 'axios';
        import { FETCH_API } from './types';

        export function searchArtist(term){
            const request = axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{term}`);
            return{
                type: FETCH_API,
                payload:request
            }
        }
```

store

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import './index.css';
        import App from './App';
        import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
        import reducers from './reducers';
        import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
        import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

        ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root'));
        registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`connect`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) statement should be

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

As  `mapDispatchToProps` is specified in wrong order, there is not `function/action` mapped to the `container`.As a result no action is called, so no `reducers`. Hense, `action & reducers` not logging anything.

Answer (score 2):

Adding more to Riyaj Khan's answer, that you should correct the syntax of connect by interchanging the position of mapStateToProps and maoDispatchToProps, you have to dispatch something intto redux. Even if you are using promise middleware you will have to dispatch the promise.

In your case `searchArtist()` is the dispatching function in you intend to use, but it should be defined inside the following function.
eg,

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        searchArtist: () => {dispatch({type:"SEARCH", payload:new Promise()})}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend cleaning up the action creator. just passing in the request is a bit unpredictable,

could do something like this

```
export function fetchArtist(term){
 fetch(`${API_URL}/${term}`)
  .then((response) => {
  if(!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
  }).then((data) => data.json())
    .then((artists) => dispatch(termSuccess(artists)))
    .catch((err) => dispatch(termError(err)))
 };
```

This is using redux thunk since I'm able to dispatch using a function. So with the other action creators, you'll end up making a termSuccess, termLoading, termError. Helps keep things a bit more organized instead of placing it all in one action creator.

Comment: Very informative, I'm going to use fetch request instead as well. Thank you!